# Request data from webserver at runtime Rust/Bevy/Wasm

Tags: rust, async-await, webassembly, bevy

I have a small game on my website and im trying to implement a leaderboard. For this to work, I need to fetch the high scores to compare the current score to and then post back the updated list when I’m done.

The gist of the issue is the lack of async options for wasm. I’m aware of crates like wasm-bindgen-futures, but am not sure how to actually utilize them in practice.

```
fn get_scores() -> … {
    let fut = reqwest::get(url);
    let res = bevy::tasks::block_on(response); // crashes at runtime
    let text = res.text(); // more async love needed here, omitted for brevity
    let highscore = serde_json::from_str(text);
    return highscore;
}
```

The problem is that Rust’s type system requires that the values be present. Now, wasm-binden-futures has `spawn_local`, but

1. the async block which it executes can’t return a value so it isn’t particularly useful for fetching data from the server
2. you can’t capture stack variables inside of it, which would be necessary for updating the high score resource within the game, given the first limitation

There’s also the option of using wasm-bindgen-futures to create a JavaScript promise, but I wasn’t sure how well that would interact with the wasm code.

`future_to_promise` seems like it might be able to coordinate information in the way that I need, but it seems like I’m still running into the issue of “Rust expects there to be a value here but there isn’t.”

I’ve toyed with the idea of handling the requests of data completely in JavaScript, but I’m not sure how to communicate that data back into the Bevy wasm app — again, with no guarantee that it’ll be ready by the time I need it.

It seems like a really solvable problem: I need some data from the server and I only need it later once the player has finished their game. I don’t necessarily need to block (which is impossible, anyway, I’ve learned) since I don’t need the data immediately. Except that the type system is demanding the value be there. It’s also perfectly acceptable for my program to pause execution without blocking and let the browser do other work while it waits, but I don’t know how to do that without an async runtime.

I wonder if there’s a way I can use Bevy’s event loop to repeatedly poll the futures myself. I’m just not fluent enough (read: not at all) with async Rust to be able to approach a problem like that.

Comment: There's always the option of running `reqwest` in [blocking mode](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/index.html)

Comment: @Jmb blocking mode does not compile when targeting wasm, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run wasm in the browser, you can use `wasm-bindgen/web-sys`. This is suggested by `reqwest`; only if you don't target the browser, there is limited support of `reqwest` for `wasm` runtime.

So it would be easier to just use the fetch API provided by the browser. Here is an [example](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/fetch.html) for this.

To execute a async task with bevy, you can use the [AsyncComputeTaskPool](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/tasks/struct.AsyncComputeTaskPool.html).

Comment: I’ve ended up at this page a few times but I’ve always discounted it because it’s an async function and requires await-ing. Notably, my entire ecosystem is *not* async functions, so I’m not sure how to use this effectively. 

I’m not sure it’s as simple as slapping `async` on everything either, considering Bevy is extremely picky about return types.